# jQuery submit validate post

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using the standard jQuery validation plugin to validate a form when the user clicks "submit."

After the form is validated, I want it to post data to a database and reveal a "success" message.

The validation part is working fine, but I can't get my two commands to happen. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#formname").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            $.post('https://www.custom.api.url.com', $(this).serialize(), function () {
                    success.show();
                    $('input[type=text]').val('');

                }
            });

</script>
```

OK, take two. This one isn't working, either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
                  var success = $('.success');

                           $("#formname").validate( {
                           submitHandler: function(form) {

                           $.post('https://www.custom.api', $(this).serialize(), function(){
                           success.show(); $('input[type=text]').val('');                


                                  });
                             });
                  });

</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(form).serialize() ?

Comment: it looks like a same origin policy issues

Comment: What does your browser console say?

Comment: @Ashalynd: Would I sub out the $("#formname").validate( { line for $("#formname").serialize() ?

Comment: Is there a reason why your code is incomplete? There several closing brackets missing and also wrong one inside your `post` callback.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder : No reason; I just keyed it in wrong. Could I trouble you to show how it *should* read? Thank you!

Comment: It's pretty easy. You have to close as many brackets as you open. So remove the lonely `}` inside your post callback function, then close your `submitHandler` function with `}` and on the bottom close the `validate` function with `});`.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder: I've edited my original post to show my revision, but it's still not working. I'll keep trying. Again, I would sincerely appreciate any guidance. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your valid code. It looks like that is also your main problem, Invalid syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formname").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('https://www.custom.api.url.com', $(form).serialize(), function () {
                success.show(); //Undefined
                $('input[type=text]').val('');
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

`$(this).serialize()` also has to be replaced with `$(form).serialize()`.

Then additionally `success` is undefined so there will be another error. But I'm not sure what exactly `success` should be.

You should use your browsers console to get notified about javascript errors. To validate your javascript you can also use [jsHint](http://jshint.com/).

Comment: Marcel: Thank you so much for writing that out, and for the tips. Heard and heeded. Unfortunately, it's still not subbing to my API URL. I'll keep plugging away at it. Thank you!